# How make a simple infinite animated progressbar

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am currently working on an Android app and I am trying to create an infinite animated progress bar using Jetpack Compose. I have been looking through the documentation but I am having trouble finding a straightforward example of how to create this. Can anyone provide a simple example or point me in the right direction to get started?"

```
@Composable
fun LoadingProgressBar(isLoading: Boolean) {
    val animation = remember {
        repeatable(periodMillis = 1000) {
            animation(0f, 1f) { progress ->
                progress
            }
        }
    }
    if (isLoading) animation.start() else animation.stop()
    Box(modifier = Modifier.preferredSize(100.dp, 5.dp).background(color = Color.Gray)) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.preferredWidth(animation[animation] * 100.dp)
                           .preferredHeight(5.dp)
                           .background(color = Color.Blue))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CircularProgressIndicator and LinearProgressIndicator are the progressbars that can be determinate or indeterminate based on which overload you pick.

```
@Composable
fun CircularProgressIndicator(
    /*@FloatRange(from = 0.0, to = 1.0)*/
    progress: Float,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
    strokeWidth: Dp = ProgressIndicatorDefaults.StrokeWidth
)
```

or

```
@Composable
fun CircularProgressIndicator(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
    strokeWidth: Dp = ProgressIndicatorDefaults.StrokeWidth
)
```

same goes for linear one either